# Implementing virtual scrolling in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, virtualscroll, vueuse

I'm trying to implement virtual scrolling behavior using [vue-virtual-scroller](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller/tree/master) library. First off, I tried to use 'useVirtualList' component from VueUse library, but I couldn't find my way in there. Then I moved on trying vue-virtual-scroller. I couldn't implement vue-virtual-scroller by looking examples on its docs.

I'll drop 2 code blocks. Each of which contains a component. One of them is a post component. Other one is the parent component called 'HomeView'. As you can see I created a PostService file under the services folder. It fetches data from API I created. The endpoint sends 1000 post objects. I couldn't find my way in implementing virtual list or virtual scrolling for performant rendering like we see on Twitter. I want to render posts vertically.

UserPost.vue:

```
<script setup>
defineProps({
  post: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
  },
})

const MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH = 300

const truncateText = (text) => {
  if (text.length > MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH) {
    return text.substring(0, MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH) + "..."
  } else {
    return text
  }
}
</script>
<template>
  <div class="post">
    <div class="post__header">
      <img :src="post.avatar" class="post__author-logo" />
      <div class="post__author-name">{{ post.name }}</div>
      <div class="post__author-slug">{{ post.username }}</div>
      <div class="post__publish-time">{{ post.publishTime }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="post__main">
      <h3 class="post__title">{{ post.postTitle }}</h3>
      <div class="post__content">{{ truncateText(post.content) }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<style>
.post {
  width: 728px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(117, 117, 117);
}

.post__header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.post__author-logo {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
}

.post__author-logo,
.post__author-name,
.post__author-slug,
.post__publish-time {
  padding: 4px;
}

.post__author-slug,
.post__publish-time {
  color: rgb(117, 117, 117);
}

.post__author-slug::after {
  content: "•";
  padding-left: 4px;
}

.post__main {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.post__title {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.post__content {
  padding: 8px 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 140%;
}
</style>
```

HomeView.vue:

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue"
import NavBar from "../components/NavBar.vue"
import UserPost from "../components/UserPost.vue"
import PostService from "../services/PostService"

const posts = ref(null)

onMounted(() => {
  PostService.getPosts()
    .then((response) => {
      posts.value = response.data
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
})
</script>
<template>
  <NavBar />
  <div class="posts">
    <UserPost v-for="post in posts" :key="post._id" :post="post" />
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.posts {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: *"I couldn't find my way in implementing X"* is not a sufficient problem description. Provide the errors you're seeing, if any. Consider creating a *runnable* [mcve] (use codesandbox.io or similar). Replace the API call with a function resolving some data placed in a local file, to give visibility over the data structure of the response.  In current form, your question is unanswerable, therefore off-topic here. For help and advice on how to improve the question, see [ask].

Comment: The code you posted so far suggests the reason why `vue-virtual-scroller` doesn't work in your project is because it has not been installed and no attempt was made at using it. Since that's not the case, please, show what you tried and did not work. This way you reduce the amount of effort required for implementing virtual scroller in your project. Most importantly, provide a *runnable* snippet which could be used to test the implementation.